# Order mySQL query by year with several year specifications

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to pull out article entries from my database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM articles 
        WHERE author LIKE ? AND title LIKE ? AND year LIKE ? 
        ORDER BY year DESC";
```

With single year specifications, the query orders the entries by year as intended:

```
1999
1998
1979
1969
...
```

Problematic is that this older database uses several publishing years in the same table cell, looking like this:

Example: `1970, 1974, 1983`  or sometimes with semicolons `1970; 1974; 1983`

This makes the script order the entries **only using the very first year** specification (1970 in the above example). Now I am looking for a way to order the entries by the most recent year specification (1983 in the above example).

So the random entries

1. 1966, 1977, **1989**
2. 1925; 1956; **1977**
3. 1933, 1947, 1975, **1999**

should be ordered like this:

1. 1933, 1947, 1975, **1999**
2. 1966, 1977, **1989**
3. 1925; 1956; **1977**

(only the most recent years 1999, 1989, 1977 are relevant for the order of the entries)

Comment: Is the most recent year always last in the list?

Comment: Yes, always the same pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the year column has at least one year, you can use

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(year,4) DESC
```